# Speech Recognition/Voice controlled form - setting the state too fast on transcript return to the parent shell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Javascript -Reactjs bug -- There is an issue I am having setting the transcript coming back as it is trying to set the state too fast. I've tried to add a debounce/throttle but it still seems to keep being invoked. I'm working on a react formik form that can be controlled via the speech recognition module.

Then there are some bugs like American English/British English and the speech sometimes returns "one" instead of "1" and the form fields itself are sensitive to values being integers or strings.

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-frog-gtcfr2

VoiceControlledForm - connects the bridge between the speech module and the formik form.

textAnalysis(transcriptText) is where it takes the spoken text and converts it into a command object to control the form if successful - validation and fine-tuning needs to happen here - //currently have set a value overriding it to test

processAnalysis(transcript, listening)

I have tried to only invoke the form control/speech analysis only after the person has stopped talking. I've added this throttle function that has seemed to have helped but without it breaks - but the throttle function needs to stop calling - I cant seem to stabilize the system.

usage - in the parent component - I am returning the transcript back and trying to feed it into a function called processAnalysis so I can set a variable in the parent and use that at this level.

```
    <SpeechRecognitionModule 
      transcript={(transcript, listening)=>this.processAnalysis(transcript, listening)}
      //transcript={(transcript)=> this.textAnalysis(transcript)}
    />
```

but I've had issues of stability when obtaining the transcript - this is where I tried to add debounces to stop it being called constantly and crashing the application

```
  processAnalysis(transcript, listening){

        function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
          var timeout;
          return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
          };
        }

        function throttle(func, wait, immediate) {
          var timeout;
          return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
              timeout = null;
              if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            if ( !timeout ) timeout = setTimeout( later, wait );
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
          };
        }


    console.log("===========><transcript", transcript);

    if(transcript.length>0 && !listening){
        console.log("WORDS ARE BEING SPOKEN");
        var that = this;

        var myEfficientFn = throttle(function() {
          console.log("CALLLLED CALLLED");
          that.textAnalysis(transcript)
        }, 1500);

        if(!listening){
          myEfficientFn();
        }
    }

    //
  }
```

textAnalysis is where it sets the variable and tries to do regex on the text for patterns

```
  textAnalysis(transcriptText){

    transcriptText ="Change my pain level to 4";

    console.log("props", this.props.schema.fields);
    var obj = this.convertSpeechTextToCommand(transcriptText, this.props.schema.fields);
    console.log("BACK -- obj", obj)
    var fieldLabel = obj.label;//"swelling";
    var fieldName = obj.name;//"swelling";
    var value = obj.value;

    var aiResponse = "Changing "+ fieldLabel +" to "+value+". Is this correct. Please repeat command if we heard the wrong value.";

    var that = this;
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
      that.updateTranscriptText(transcriptText);
      that.updateAIResponseText(aiResponse)
    }, 1)

    console.log("xxx", this.props.schema);
 
    //this.setState({ai_response: })

    var controlledFields = [
      { name: fieldName, value: value }
    ]
    this.setState({
      controlledFields: controlledFields
    })    
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.handleChange()
    }, 1)


    /*
    var controlledFields = [
      { name: "wound_opening", value: [] },
      { name: "swelling", value: 2 }
    ]
    this.setState({
      controlledFields: controlledFields
    })

    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.handleChange()
    }, 1)
    */

  }
```

but when I set the state it crashes like its being asked to set the state too many times.

```
  updateTranscriptText(transcriptText){
    this.setState({ transcriptText: transcriptText });
    console.log("===========transcriptText", transcriptText);
  }

  updateAIResponseText(aiResponse){
    this.setState({ aiResponse: aiResponse });
    console.log("===========aiResponse", aiResponse);
  }
```